# Error running Selenium IDE "Error: Permission denied to access property 'nr@context'

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-ide

Starting this morning (4/3/14), I have been getting errors when my Selenium IDE tests run against my site.  These tests were working just fine yesterday.  I am running FF 25, Selenium IDE 2.5.0.  Whenever it gets to a step where it needs to click or clickandwait, I get this error,

"Error: Permission denied to access property 'nr@context' Filename -> XXXXX,  lineNumber -> 5, columnNumber -> 376.

The filename changes depending on what page I happen to be on when running the test.  It seems like a javascript error, but I can't see anything in the console.  Could there have been a blind update to FF that occurred last night, since all these tests were working flawlessly yesterday afternoon?

Klendathu

Comment: I'm also having this problem, started at the same time too. Our Selenium/Webdriver smoke tests fail in production but pass in the QA environment. I was wondering if it had anything to do with a third party JavaScript file like Google Analytics...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have found it!

In my case the problem with nr@context apear on servers where enabled [New Relic](http://newrelic.com/real-user-monitoring) monitoring and 'new relic script' present on the page (this script contains ...a="nr@context";...)

Comment: That would be consistent with our site, we are using new relic. problem is, how to resolve it?  Any why did it just start happening today?  Maybe some issue with New Relic?

Comment: Awesome find. We fit in this category too. Now how do we fix it? :)

Comment: I've raised a support ticket with NewRelic and they're taking a look. I'll advise further when I have more info.

Comment: Until this is fixed, you can get around it by disabling the Browser Beta module in New Relic - go to your app, then Browser Beta > Settings and turn it off. Hopefully it'll be fixed soon. My Selenium RC jobs all complete successfully with Browser Beta turned off.

Comment: Nice job! I can confirm too that I see tests failing on a page where New Relic is enabled, hopefully this is fixed soon

Comment: I can confirm that turning that option off fixed the issues I was having with Selenium IDE tests failing with that error.

Comment: I currently use Selenium to perform external tests on our sites and others. I dont really have the option of changing the browser beta module on the sites that I perform tests on. I attempted to disable all javascript at the start of each tests only to find that the rest of my page is no longer responsive. Waiting for a solution / update

Answer (score 4):

New Relic Browser agent v378, which contains a fix for this issue, was released this morning. You may need to restart your application server to pickup the new version.

To verify that you're running it, search the HTML source for 378.min.js